# Nativescript Angular - Could not find support-v4.jar

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am running sample groceries example of Nativescript with Angular and Typescript. I followed the steps from 
http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-1#11-install-nativescript-and-configure-your-environment

I am getting this error.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> * What went wrong:
>
> A problem occurred configuring root project 'groceries'.
>
> Could not find support-v4.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1).
>
> Searched in the following locations:
>         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/24.1.1/support-v4-24.1.1.jar

Here is the output of $tns run android --justlaunch --log trace

```
execFile: /home/charan/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb "help"
execFile: /home/charan/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb "help"
spawn: /home/charan/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb "--help"
Socket {
  _connecting: false,
  _hadError: false,
  _handle: 
   Pipe {
     _externalStream: {},
     fd: 13,
     writeQueueSize: 0,
     owner: [Circular],
     onread: [Function: onread],
     reading: true },
  _parent: null,
  _host: null,
  _readableState: 
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: [],
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: null,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: true,
     sync: false,
     needReadable: true,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     ranOut: false,
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: true,
  domain: null,
  _events: 
   { end: { [Function: g] listener: [Function: onend] },
     finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
     _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
     close: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 4,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _writableState: 
   WritableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     needDrain: false,
     ending: false,
     ended: false,
     finished: false,
     decodeStrings: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     length: 0,
     writing: false,
     corked: 0,
     sync: true,
     bufferProcessing: false,
     onwrite: [Function],
     writecb: null,
     writelen: 0,
     bufferedRequest: null,
     lastBufferedRequest: null,
     pendingcb: 0,
     prefinished: false,
     errorEmitted: false },
  writable: false,
  allowHalfOpen: false,
  destroyed: false,
  bytesRead: 0,
  _bytesDispatched: 0,
  _sockname: null,
  _writev: null,
  _pendingData: null,
  _pendingEncoding: '' }
Exec uname -a 
 stdout: Linux 41-S02 4.4.0-36-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 11 18:01:55 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

 stderr: 
Exec npm -v 
 stdout: 3.5.2

 stderr: 
spawn: java "-version"
Exec node-gyp -v 
 stdout: v3.0.3

 stderr: 
Exec '/home/charan/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb' version 
 stdout: Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.36
Revision af05c7354fe1-android

 stderr: 
spawn: /home/charan/Android/Sdk/tools/android "-h"
Result when throw error is false:
{ stdout: '\n       Usage:\n       android [global options] action [action options]\n       Global options:\n  -s --silent     : Silent mode, shows errors only.\n  -v --verbose    : Verbose mode, shows errors, warnings and all messages.\n     --clear-cache: Clear the SDK Manager repository manifest cache.\n  -h --help       : Help on a specific command.\n\n                                                                    Valid\n                                                                    actions\n                                                                    are\n                                                                    composed\n                                                                    of a verb\n                                                                    and an\n                                                                    optional\n                                                                    direct\n                                                                    object:\n-    sdk              : Displays the SDK Manager window.\n-    avd              : Displays the AVD Manager window.\n-   list              : Lists existing targets or virtual devices.\n-   list avd          : Lists existing Android Virtual Devices.\n-   list target       : Lists existing targets.\n-   list device       : Lists existing devices.\n-   list sdk          : Lists remote SDK repository.\n- create avd          : Creates a new Android Virtual Device.\n-   move avd          : Moves or renames an Android Virtual Device.\n- delete avd          : Deletes an Android Virtual Device.\n- update avd          : Updates an Android Virtual Device to match the folders\n                        of a new SDK.\n- create project      : Creates a new Android project.\n- update project      : Updates an Android project (must already have an\n                        AndroidManifest.xml).\n- create test-project : Creates a new Android project for a test package.\n- update test-project : Updates the Android project for a test package (must\n                        already have an AndroidManifest.xml).\n- create lib-project  : Creates a new Android library project.\n- update lib-project  : Updates an Android library project (must already have\n                        an AndroidManifest.xml).\n- create uitest-project: Creates a new UI test project.\n- update adb          : Updates adb to support the USB devices declared in the\n                        SDK add-ons.\n- update sdk          : Updates the SDK by suggesting new platforms to install\n                        if available.\n',
  stderr: '',
  exitCode: 1 }
Exec mono --version 
 stdout:  
 stderr: /bin/sh: 1: mono: not found

Exec git --version 
 stdout: git version 2.7.4

 stderr: 
Exec gradle -v 
 stdout:  
 stderr: /bin/sh: 1: gradle: not found

Exec "javac" -version 
 stdout:  
 stderr: javac 1.8.0_91

System information:
{ procInfo: 'nativescript/2.3.0',
  platform: 'linux',
  os: 'Linux 41-S02 4.4.0-36-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 11 18:01:55 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux\n',
  shell: '/bin/bash',
  dotNetVer: null,
  procArch: 'x64',
  nodeVer: 'v4.2.6',
  npmVer: '3.5.2',
  javaVer: '1.8.0',
  nodeGypVer: 'v3.0.3\n',
  xcodeVer: null,
  xcodeprojGemLocation: null,
  itunesInstalled: false,
  cocoapodVer: null,
  adbVer: 'Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.36',
  androidInstalled: true,
  monoVer: null,
  gitVer: '2.7.4',
  gradleVer: null,
  javacVersion: '1.8.0_91' }
Initializing analytics statuses.
Analytics statuses: 
{ TrackFeatureUsage: 0, TrackExceptions: 0 }
Trying to track feature 'Non-interactive' with value 'run'.
AnalyticsInstallationID: a0b367e3-2032-4617-b4f4-4497da9fac9d
monitor not started
monitor not started
monitor not started
monitor has started, connecting to http://5752dabccfc54c4ab82aea9626b7338e.monitor-eqatec.com/json.ashx
Analytics statuses: 
{ TrackFeatureUsage: 0, TrackExceptions: 0 }
Trying to track feature 'NodeJSVersion' with value '4_2_6'.
Waiting for analytics to send information. Will check in a 1000ms.
Statistics was sent successfully (xhr).
Waiting for analytics to send information. Will check in a 1000ms. Remaining time is: 29000
Statistics was sent successfully (xhr).
Waiting for analytics to send information. Will check in a 1000ms.
Waiting for analytics to send information. Will check in a 1000ms. Remaining time is: 28000
Statistics was sent successfully (xhr).
Waiting for analytics to send information. Will check in a 1000ms. Remaining time is: 29000
Looking for project in '/var/www/ns/groceries_ts/sample-Groceries/platforms/android'
Looking for project in '/var/www/ns/groceries_ts/sample-Groceries/platforms'
Looking for project in '/var/www/ns/groceries_ts/sample-Groceries'
Project directory is '/var/www/ns/groceries_ts/sample-Groceries'.
Analytics statuses: 
{ TrackFeatureUsage: 0, TrackExceptions: 0 }
Trying to track feature 'Non-interactive' with value 'run|android'.
Waiting for analytics to send information. Will check in a 1000ms.
Statistics was sent successfully (xhr).
Waiting for analytics to send information. Will check in a 1000ms. Remaining time is: 29000
startLookingForDevices; platform is Android
spawn: /home/charan/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb "start-server"
Result when throw error is false:
{ stdout: '', stderr: '', exitCode: 0 }
spawn: /home/charan/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb "devices"
spawn: /home/charan/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb "-s" "emulator-5554" "shell" "getprop"
Result when throw error is false:
{ stdout: '[dalvik.vm.dex2oat-Xms]: [64m]\r\n[dalvik.vm.dex2oat-Xmx]: [512m]\r\n[dalvik.vm.heapsize]: [384m]\r\n[dalvik.vm.image-dex2oat-Xms]: [64m]\r\n[dalvik.vm.image-dex2oat-Xmx]: [64m]\r\n[dalvik.vm.isa.x86.features]: [default]\r\n[dalvik.vm.isa.x86_64.features]: [default]\r\n[dalvik.vm.lockprof.threshold]: [500]\r\n[dalvik.vm.stack-trace-file]: [/data/anr/traces.txt]\r\n[debug.force_rtl]: [0]\r\n[dev.bootcomplete]: [1]\r\n[gsm.current.phone-type]: [1]\r\n[gsm.defaultpdpcontext.active]: [true]\r\n[gsm.network.type]: [UMTS]\r\n[gsm.nitz.time]: [1474530944793]\r\n[gsm.operator.alpha]: [Android]\r\n[gsm.operator.iso-country]: [us]\r\n[gsm.operator.isroaming]: [false]\r\n[gsm.operator.numeric]: [310260]\r\n[gsm.sim.operator.alpha]: [Android]\r\n[gsm.sim.operator.iso-country]: [us]\r\n[gsm.sim.operator.numeric]: [310260]\r\n[gsm.sim.state]: [READY]\r\n[gsm.version.ril-impl]: [android reference-ril 1.0]\r\n[init.svc.adbd]: [running]\r\n[init.svc.bootanim]: [stopped]\r\n[init.svc.console]: [running]\r\n[init.svc.debuggerd64]: [running]\r\n[init.svc.debuggerd]: [running]\r\n[init.svc.drm]: [running]\r\n[init.svc.fuse_sdcard]: [running]\r\n[init.svc.goldfish-logcat]: [stopped]\r\n[init.svc.goldfish-setup]: [stopped]\r\n[init.svc.healthd]: [running]\r\n[init.svc.installd]: [running]\r\n[init.svc.keystore]: [running]\r\n[init.svc.lmkd]: [running]\r\n[init.svc.logd]: [running]\r\n[init.svc.media]: [running]\r\n[init.svc.netd]: [running]\r\n[init.svc.qemu-props]: [stopped]\r\n[init.svc.ril-daemon]: [running]\r\n[init.svc.servicemanager]: [running]\r\n[init.svc.surfaceflinger]: [running]\r\n[init.svc.ueventd]: [running]\r\n[init.svc.vold]: [running]\r\n[init.svc.zygote]: [running]\r\n[init.svc.zygote_secondary]: [running]\r\n[net.bt.name]: [Android]\r\n[net.change]: [net.dns1]\r\n[net.dns1]: [10.0.2.3]\r\n[net.eth0.dns1]: [10.0.2.3]\r\n[net.eth0.gw]: [10.0.2.2]\r\n[net.gprs.local-ip]: [10.0.2.15]\r\n[net.hostname]: [android-995f9ae46c30a1a4]\r\n[net.qtaguid_enabled]: [0]\r\n[net.tcp.default_init_rwnd]: [60]\r\n[persist.sys.dalvik.vm.lib.2]: [libart.so]\r\n[persist.sys.profiler_ms]: [0]\r\n[persist.sys.timezone]: [Asia/Kolkata]\r\n[persist.sys.usb.config]: [adb]\r\n[qemu.gles]: [1]\r\n[qemu.hw.mainkeys]: [0]\r\n[qemu.sf.fake_camera]: [none]\r\n[qemu.sf.lcd_density]: [560]\r\n[rild.libargs]: [-d /dev/ttyS0]\r\n[rild.libpath]: [/system/lib/libreference-ril.so]\r\n[ro.allow.mock.location]: [0]\r\n[ro.baseband]: [unknown]\r\n[ro.board.platform]: []\r\n[ro.boot.hardware]: [ranchu]\r\n[ro.bootloader]: [unknown]\r\n[ro.bootmode]: [unknown]\r\n[ro.build.characteristics]: [default]\r\n[ro.build.date.utc]: [1469055163]\r\n[ro.build.date]: [Wed Jul 20 22:52:43 UTC 2016]\r\n[ro.build.description]: [sdk_google_phone_x86_64-userdebug 5.1.1 LMY48X 3079158 test-keys]\r\n[ro.build.display.id]: [sdk_google_phone_x86_64-userdebug 5.1.1 LMY48X 3079158 test-keys]\r\n[ro.build.fingerprint]: [Android/sdk_google_phone_x86_64/generic_x86_64:5.1.1/LMY48X/3079158:userdebug/test-keys]\r\n[ro.build.flavor]: [sdk_google_phone_x86_64-userdebug]\r\n[ro.build.host]: [wpdu8.hot.corp.google.com]\r\n[ro.build.id]: [LMY48X]\r\n[ro.build.product]: [generic_x86_64]\r\n[ro.build.tags]: [test-keys]\r\n[ro.build.type]: [userdebug]\r\n[ro.build.user]: [android-build]\r\n[ro.build.version.all_codenames]: [REL]\r\n[ro.build.version.base_os]: []\r\n[ro.build.version.codename]: [REL]\r\n[ro.build.version.incremental]: [3079158]\r\n[ro.build.version.release]: [5.1.1]\r\n[ro.build.version.sdk]: [22]\r\n[ro.build.version.security_patch]: [2015-11-01]\r\n[ro.com.google.locationfeatures]: [1]\r\n[ro.config.alarm_alert]: [Alarm_Classic.ogg]\r\n[ro.config.nocheckin]: [yes]\r\n[ro.config.notification_sound]: [OnTheHunt.ogg]\r\n[ro.crypto.state]: [unencrypted]\r\n[ro.dalvik.vm.native.bridge]: [0]\r\n[ro.debuggable]: [1]\r\n[ro.factorytest]: [0]\r\n[ro.hardware.audio.primary]: [goldfish]\r\n[ro.hardware]: [ranchu]\r\n[ro.kernel.android.checkjni]: [1]\r\n[ro.kernel.android.qemud]: [1]\r\n[ro.kernel.androidboot.hardware]: [ranchu]\r\n[ro.kernel.clocksource]: [pit]\r\n[ro.kernel.qemu.gles]: [1]\r\n[ro.kernel.qemu]: [1]\r\n[ro.opengles.version]: [131072]\r\n[ro.product.board]: []\r\n[ro.product.brand]: [Android]\r\n[ro.product.cpu.abi]: [x86_64]\r\n[ro.product.cpu.abilist32]: [x86]\r\n[ro.product.cpu.abilist64]: [x86_64]\r\n[ro.product.cpu.abilist]: [x86_64,x86]\r\n[ro.product.device]: [generic_x86_64]\r\n[ro.product.locale.language]: [en]\r\n[ro.product.locale.region]: [US]\r\n[ro.product.manufacturer]: [unknown]\r\n[ro.product.model]: [Android SDK built for x86_64]\r\n[ro.product.name]: [sdk_google_phone_x86_64]\r\n[ro.radio.use-ppp]: [no]\r\n[ro.revision]: [0]\r\n[ro.runtime.firstboot]: [1474530952328]\r\n[ro.secure]: [1]\r\n[ro.serialno]: []\r\n[ro.wifi.channels]: []\r\n[ro.zygote]: [zygote64_32]\r\n[selinux.reload_policy]: [1]\r\n[service.bootanim.exit]: [1]\r\n[status.battery.level]: [5]\r\n[status.battery.level_raw]: [50]\r\n[status.battery.level_scale]: [9]\r\n[status.battery.state]: [Slow]\r\n[sys.boot_completed]: [1]\r\n[sys.settings_secure_version]: [2]\r\n[sys.sysctl.extra_free_kbytes]: [43200]\r\n[sys.sysctl.tcp_def_init_rwnd]: [60]\r\n[sys.usb.config]: [adb]\r\n[sys.usb.state]: [adb]\r\n[wlan.driver.status]: [unloaded]\r\n[xmpp.auto-presence]: [true]\r\n',
  stderr: '',
  exitCode: 0 }
{ characteristics: 'default',
  'date.utc': '1469055163',
  date: 'Wed Jul 20 22:52:43 UTC 2016',
  description: 'sdk_google_phone_x86_64-userdebug 5.1.1 LMY48X 3079158 test-keys',
  'display.id': 'sdk_google_phone_x86_64-userdebug 5.1.1 LMY48X 3079158 test-keys',
  fingerprint: 'Android/sdk_google_phone_x86_64/generic_x86_64:5.1.1/LMY48X/3079158:userdebug/test-keys',
  flavor: 'sdk_google_phone_x86_64-userdebug',
  host: 'wpdu8.hot.corp.google.com',
  id: 'LMY48X',
  product: 'generic_x86_64',
  tags: 'test-keys',
  type: 'userdebug',
  user: 'android-build',
  all_codenames: 'REL',
  base_os: '',
  codename: 'REL',
  incremental: '3079158',
  release: '5.1.1',
  sdk: '22',
  security_patch: '2015-11-01',
  board: '',
  brand: 'Android',
  'cpu.abi': 'x86_64',
  'cpu.abilist32': 'x86',
  'cpu.abilist64': 'x86_64',
  'cpu.abilist': 'x86_64,x86',
  device: 'generic_x86_64',
  'locale.language': 'en',
  'locale.region': 'US',
  manufacturer: 'unknown',
  model: 'Android SDK built for x86_64',
  name: 'sdk_google_phone_x86_64' }
{ characteristics: 'default',
  'date.utc': '1469055163',
  date: 'Wed Jul 20 22:52:43 UTC 2016',
  description: 'sdk_google_phone_x86_64-userdebug 5.1.1 LMY48X 3079158 test-keys',
  'display.id': 'sdk_google_phone_x86_64-userdebug 5.1.1 LMY48X 3079158 test-keys',
  fingerprint: 'Android/sdk_google_phone_x86_64/generic_x86_64:5.1.1/LMY48X/3079158:userdebug/test-keys',
  flavor: 'sdk_google_phone_x86_64-userdebug',
  host: 'wpdu8.hot.corp.google.com',
  id: 'LMY48X',
  product: 'generic_x86_64',
  tags: 'test-keys',
  type: 'userdebug',
  user: 'android-build',
  all_codenames: 'REL',
  base_os: '',
  codename: 'REL',
  incremental: '3079158',
  release: '5.1.1',
  sdk: '22',
  security_patch: '2015-11-01',
  board: '',
  brand: 'Android',
  'cpu.abi': 'x86_64',
  'cpu.abilist32': 'x86',
  'cpu.abilist64': 'x86_64',
  'cpu.abilist': 'x86_64,x86',
  device: 'generic_x86_64',
  'locale.language': 'en',
  'locale.region': 'US',
  manufacturer: 'unknown',
  model: 'Android SDK built for x86_64',
  name: 'sdk_google_phone_x86_64' }
execFile: /home/charan/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb "devices"
{ identifier: 'emulator-5554',
  displayName: 'sdk_google_phone_x86_64',
  model: 'Android SDK built for x86_64',
  version: '5.1.1',
  vendor: 'Android',
  platform: 'Android',
  status: 'Connected',
  errorHelp: null,
  isTablet: false,
  type: 'Emulator' }
Found device with identifier 'emulator-5554'
Hooks directories: [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/hooks',
  '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/hooks',
  '/var/www/ns/groceries_ts/sample-Groceries/hooks' ]
BeforeHookName for command prepare is before-prepare
Executing before-prepare hook from /var/www/ns/groceries_ts/sample-Groceries/hooks/before-prepare/nativescript-dev-typescript.js
Executing before-prepare hook at location /var/www/ns/groceries_ts/sample-Groceries/hooks/before-prepare/nativescript-dev-typescript.js in-process
Found peer TypeScript 1.8.10
Hook promises to signal completion
Hook completed
Existing AndroidManifest.xml is correct.
Existing AndroidManifest.xml is correct.
spawn: /home/charan/Android/Sdk/tools/android "list" "targets"
Result when throw error is false:
{ stdout: 'Available Android targets:\n----------\nid: 1 or "android-19"\n     Name: Android 4.4.2\n     Type: Platform\n     API level: 19\n     Revision: 4\n     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in\n Tag/ABIs : no ABIs.\n----------\nid: 2 or "android-22"\n     Name: Android 5.1.1\n     Type: Platform\n     API level: 22\n     Revision: 2\n     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in\n Tag/ABIs : no ABIs.\n----------\nid: 3 or "android-23"\n     Name: Android 6.0\n     Type: Platform\n     API level: 23\n     Revision: 3\n     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in\n Tag/ABIs : no ABIs.\n----------\nid: 4 or "android-24"\n     Name: Android 7.0\n     Type: Platform\n     API level: 24\n     Revision: 1\n     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in\n Tag/ABIs : no ABIs.\n',
  stderr: '',
  exitCode: 0 }
Available Android targets:
----------
id: 1 or "android-19"
     Name: Android 4.4.2
     Type: Platform
     API level: 19
     Revision: 4
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
 Tag/ABIs : no ABIs.
----------
id: 2 or "android-22"
     Name: Android 5.1.1
     Type: Platform
     API level: 22
     Revision: 2
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
 Tag/ABIs : no ABIs.
----------
id: 3 or "android-23"
     Name: Android 6.0
     Type: Platform
     API level: 23
     Revision: 3
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
 Tag/ABIs : no ABIs.
----------
id: 4 or "android-24"
     Name: Android 7.0
     Type: Platform
     API level: 24
     Revision: 1
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
 Tag/ABIs : no ABIs.

Directories found in /home/charan/Android/Sdk/build-tools are 23.0.1, 23.0.3, 24.0.0, 24.0.1, 24.0.2
Versions found in /home/charan/Android/Sdk/build-tools are 23.0.1, 23.0.3, 24.0.0, 24.0.1, 24.0.2
Selected version is:  24.0.2
Selected targetSdk is: 24
Directories found in /home/charan/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7 are 18.0.0, 19.0.0, 19.0.1, 19.1.0, 20.0.0, 21.0.0, 21.0.2, 21.0.3, 22.0.0, 22.1.0, 22.1.1, 22.2.0, 22.2.1, 23.0.0, 23.0.1, 23.1.0, 23.1.1, 23.2.0, 23.2.1, 23.3.0, 23.4.0, 24.0.0, 24.0.0-alpha1, 24.0.0-alpha2, 24.0.0-beta1, 24.1.0, 24.1.1, maven-metadata.xml, maven-metadata.xml.md5, maven-metadata.xml.sha1
Versions found in /home/charan/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7 are 18.0.0, 19.0.0, 19.0.1, 19.1.0, 20.0.0, 21.0.0, 21.0.2, 21.0.3, 22.0.0, 22.1.0, 22.1.1, 22.2.0, 22.2.1, 23.0.0, 23.0.1, 23.1.0, 23.1.1, 23.2.0, 23.2.1, 23.3.0, 23.4.0, 24.0.0, 24.0.0, 24.0.0, 24.0.0, 24.1.0, 24.1.1
Selected version is:  24.1.1
Selected AppCompat version is: 24.1.1
spawn: /var/www/ns/groceries_ts/sample-Groceries/platforms/android/gradlew "clean" "-PcompileSdk=android-24" "-PtargetSdk=__APILEVEL__" "-PbuildToolsVersion=24.0.2" "-PsupportVersion=24.1.1"

:config phase:  createDefaultIncludeFiles

:config phase:  copyAarDependencies

:config phase:  addAarDependencies
    +adding dependency: /var/www/ns/groceries_ts/sample-Groceries/platforms/android/libs/aar/widgets-release.aar

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7.507 secs
[Error: Command /var/www/ns/groceries_ts/sample-Groceries/platforms/android/gradlew failed with exit code 1]
Error: Command /var/www/ns/groceries_ts/sample-Groceries/platforms/android/gradlew failed with exit code 1
    at FiberFuture.Future.wait (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fibers/future.js:566:15)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/services/platform-service.js:246:118
    at Function.settle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fibers/future.js:249:26)
    at FiberFuture.Future.wait (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fibers/future.js:565:10)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/helpers.js:224:36
    at PlatformService.descriptor.value [as preparePlatformCore] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/helpers.js:191:24)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/services/platform-service.js:193:26
    at Function.settle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fibers/future.js:249:26)
    at FiberFuture.Future.wait (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fibers/future.js:565:10)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/services/platform-service.js:280:50
    at Function.settle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fibers/future.js:249:26)
    at FiberFuture.Future.wait (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fibers/future.js:565:10)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/services/platform-service.js:380:140
    at Function.settle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fibers/future.js:249:26)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/mobile/mobile-core/devices-service.js:257:28
    at arrayMap (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:574:23)
    - - - - -
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/child-process.js:91:38)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:821:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
Processing node_modules failed. Error: Command /var/www/ns/groceries_ts/sample-Groceries/platforms/android/gradlew failed with exit code 1
Analytics statuses: 
{ TrackFeatureUsage: 0, TrackExceptions: 0 }
Trying to track exception with message 'Processing node_modules failed. Error: Command /var/www/ns/groceries_ts/sample-Groceries/platforms/android/gradlew failed with exit code 1'.
Waiting for analytics to send information. Will check in a 1000ms.
Statistics was sent successfully (xhr).
Waiting for analytics to send information. Will check in a 1000ms. Remaining time is: 29000
```

Comment: I'm having a very similar issue on a React Native project (`Could not find support-v4.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0)`) after having updated some of the SDK packages (I think...). I'm not able to create even a trivial project without the error now, even after having reinstalled everything, so I'm feeling something was recently broken in the SDK.

Comment: Update: today I updated again some SDK packages in android studio and everything works now. Either it was fixed or I randomly did the right thing...

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and type `android`

The following dialog will appear. 
Scroll down to 'extras' and find 'Android Support Repository'. Check it then click "Install Packages..."

[image]

Once it has installed your build should complete without errors!

Answer (score 0):

After updating your Android Support Repository add the latest version of support-v4.jar to your dependency at the module-level build.gradle file like this.

```
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1"
```

You can always check for the latest version after the update from the sdk directory C:...\your_sdk_location\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-v4